# Como acceder a la posicion de un array en typescript ANGULAR (al acceder sale indefinido aun teniendo un elemento)

Tags: array, angular, typescript

hoy tengo este problema que es sencillo pero no logro solucionar en angular 14, Tengo un arreglo que guarda el nombre de pacientes el cual es el siguiente:

```
pacienteNombre: String[] = ['Luis Daniel', 'Jose Carlos', 'Luisa Martinez'];
```

En mi componente html lo recorro con un *ngFor en una etiqueta li:

```
    <ol>
    <li class="paciente" *ngFor="let patient of pacienteNombre">{{patient}}</li>
    </ol>
```

En la pagina se muestra bien el despliege de los 3 nombres, pero cuando quiero acceder a una posicion en especifico en el componente.ts me marca que esta indefinido, utilizo getElementsByClassName para que me regrese la coleccion de li creados y poder acceder pero me sale indefinido:

```
 posicion: any;

 this.posicion = document.getElementsByClassName("paciente")
 console.log(this.posicion[0]);
```

Estructura component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-registro',
  templateUrl: './registro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registro.component.css']
})
export class RegistroComponent implements OnInit{
  

  constructor(){}
   
  pacienteNombre: String[] = ['Luis Daniel', 'Jose Carlos', 'Luisa Martinez'];
  posicion: any;

  ngOnInit() {
   
    this.posicion = document.getElementsByClassName("paciente")
    console.log(this.posicion[0]);


  }
}
```

Si me pudieran orientar, lo agradeceria mucho, de ante mano gracias por leer,buen dia.

Comment: ¿En qué momento del `lifecycle` estás  haciendo el query de los elementos?

Comment: Hola, buen dia!, lo hago después de que los elementos se recorran :D

Comment: incluye la estructura de tu componente.ts

Comment: Claro que si!:)

Comment: Listo amigo, ya quedo

Comment: Durante `onInit` es probable que los elementos no estén en pantalla. Te recomendaría cambiar tu código a `ngAfterContentInit`. También deberías leer la siguiente documentación https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Intente cambiarlo a nfAfterContentInit pero son los mismos resultados, igual gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es que estás intentando leer el DOM en el evento OnInit.

Cuando se ejecuta OnInit el DOM aún no ha sido representado, así que no puede encontrar el elemento.

Existe otro evento que es ngAfterViewInit que se ejecuta cuando ya se ha mostrado la vista y es el que deberías utilizar. Hazlo de esta manera

1. Importa AfterVieInit desde el core de Angular
2. Haz que la clase lo implemente
3. Crea el evento ngAfterViewinit y ejecuta ahí tu código

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       templateUrl: './app.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
       pacienteNombre: String[] = ['Luis Daniel', 'Jose Carlos', 'Luisa Martinez'];
       posicion: any;

       ngOnInit() { }

       ngAfterViewInit(): void {
           this.posicion = document.getElementsByClassName("paciente")
           console.log(this.posicion[0]);
       }
   }
   ```

Por otro lado, esta práctica de acceder directamente al DOM está totalmente desaconsejada en Angular ya que puede interferir con el funcionamiento del propio Angular, con resultados inesperados.

En este caso te recomendaría utilizar variables de plantilla para acceder a los elementos de la vista. Si no sabes cómo hacerlo (no voy a extenderme aquí explicándolo por ser muy extenso), puedes seguir mi curso de Angular que he iniciado recientemente en Youtube. Puedes encontrar el link en mi perfil.